# Find what files are currently in process while using Task Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, .net, task

I have `Winforms` application with list of files that my application play.
because i want to add the option to simultaneous play several files i added this:

```
private IEnumerable<string> _source;
public void doWork()
{
    _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var token = _tokenSource.Token;
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            Parallel.ForEach(_source,
                new ParallelOptions
                {
                    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = _parallelThreads //limit number of parallel threads 
                },
                file =>
                {
                    if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                        return;
                    //do work...
                });
        }
        catch (Exception)
        { }

    }, _tokenSource.Token).ContinueWith(
            t =>
            {
                //finish...
            }
        , TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() //to ContinueWith (update UI) from UI thread
        );
}
```

In this case i can play more than 1 file but because i want to know which files currently in process my question is if it's possible to know what files from  `_source` are currently in process

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is :)
Put richTextBox and button on form to test it.

The most important thing here is to use InvokeIfRequired, which allows you to avoid cross-thread exceptions when accessing UI-thread controlls from non-UI threads, which you're creating.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication4
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private IEnumerable<string> _source = new List<string>() { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" };
        public void doWork()
        {
            CancellationTokenSource _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var token = _tokenSource.Token;
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    Parallel.ForEach(_source,
                        new ParallelOptions
                        {
                            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 //limit number of parallel threads 
                        },
                        file =>
                        {
                            if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                                return;
                            if (InvokeRequired)
                            {
                                Invoke((Action<string>)richTextBox1.AppendText, "Task no: " + Task.CurrentId + " processing file: " + file + Environment.NewLine);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                richTextBox1.AppendText("Task no: " + Task.CurrentId + " processing file: " + file + Environment.NewLine);
                            }
                        });
                }
                catch (Exception)
                { }

            }, _tokenSource.Token).ContinueWith(
                    t =>
                    {
                        //finish...
                    }
                , TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() //to ContinueWith (update UI) from UI thread
                );
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            doWork();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why i need richTextBox ? all i want is the files index from my list im order to mark this file in my list